# Is there a way to delete a folder that claims to be in use?

Tags: powershell, del

I used the command *Del "L:\Do NOT Use"* and get the following error:
[PowerShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAzu8.png)

The folder is empty; there are no hidden items, either.

I am the trustee of the folder and have all rights associated to that folder.

Note: The reason the folder is named "Do NOT Use" is because I named it that.

Comment: Process Explorer can show you which programs have an open handle for a file/folder if you search inside it. Have you tried that? Or do you need a programmatic solution?

Comment: Not sure if I should have mentioned that this folder is on a network location? I don't believe Procese Explorer is able to process that type of process, does it?

Comment: Check out this script: https://github.com/pldmgg/misc-powershell/blob/master/MyFunctions/PowerShellCore_Compatible/Get-FileLockProcess.ps1

Comment: Use share management to check who has the directory open on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up unchecking the "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" under "Folder Options">"View", then I was able to delete the file that was causing the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).